# What's the proper way to check the object type for Generic object?

Tags: java, object, casting, warnings, instanceof

I got a warning message on Object Casting while compiling my code. I have no idea how to fix it with my current knowledge....
Let's say I have a Generic Object `MyGenericObj<T>` it is extends from a non-Generic Object `MyObj`

Here is a sample code:

```
MyObj obj1 = new MyGenericObj<Integer>();
if (obj1 instanceof MyGenericObj) {
    //I was trying to check if it's instance of MyGenericObj<Integer>
    //but my IDE saying this is wrong syntax.... 
    MyGenericObj<Integer> obj2 = (MyGenericObj<Integer>) obj1;
    //This line of code will cause a warning message when compiling 
}
```

Could you please let me know what's the proper way of doing this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of [*type erasure*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/339699/335858), there is no way to do that: `MyGenericObj<Integer>` is actually a `MyGenericObj<Object>` behind the scene, regardless of its type parameter.

One way around this would be adding a `Class<T>` property to your generic object, like this:

```
class MyGenericObject<T> {
    private final Class<T> theClass;
    public Class<T> getTypeArg() {
        return theClass;
    }
    MyGenericObject(Class<T> theClass, ... the rest of constructor parameters) {
        this.theClass = theClass;
        ... the rest of the constructor ...
    }
}
```

Now you can use `getTypeArg` to find the actual class of the type parameter, compare it to `Integer.class`, and make a decision based on that.

Comment: First Thanks for your help. So you mean in 'theClass' object, you have a place to save the object type, then you compare that to 'Integer.class'?

Comment: @user2296188 Essentially, yes - you write something like this: `if (i instanceof MyGenericObject && ((MyGenericObject)i).getTypeArg() == Integer.class) {...}`. Take a look at this demo on ideone ([link](http://ideone.com/j85Uj9)) for a working example.

Comment: I got it now~~ Thank you very much!!! I will try it out and see if the warning message is cleared...